# Clean Windows 10 install fails on SSD fails with error code 0x8007025D

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

Yesterday I tried installing windows 10 on my SSD with a bootable USB stick for windows 10, created with Rufus.

However, no matter what I try, i always get thrown out at ~32-40% of the second installation part, "preparing files for installation"

Everytime I am greeted with an error code of "0x8007025D", without any further explanation what could be wrong.

I tried redownloading a fresh iso file a few times, but that doesn't seem to make any difference at all. However, I also tried running the installation on a VM, it seems to work there without error code, so it might not even be the iso.

Could either my stick or Rufus be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Is there any way you can verify crc/md5 etc. of the ISO to make sure it's a valid download?....also make sure you are using latest version of Rufus.

Comment: If you use a recent version of Rufus, you can click on the `#` sign at the bottom to compute the SHA-1 of the ISO selected. Then you should google that value to confirm that this is a known SHA-1. If you don't get any hits, your ISO is probably corrupted. Oh, and `0x8007025d` seems to be the code for `ERROR_BAD_COMPRESSION_BUFFER`, which could have to do with a corrupted ISO or bad RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

> Format the primary drive partition before installing the OS.

I had exactly the same problem when I tried installing a Windows 10 ISO on a new Lenovo G40-45 laptop using the same Rufus tool. The problem was I didn't format the primary drive and I got this same error code `0x8007025d`. Once I did the formatting before selecting it as the primary partition to install the OS on that partition, the windows files loaded without any errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work for me on a Z87X-D3H with a 3x 128GB SSD RAID0 setup. Come on Microsoft!

Comment: Downloading a new ISO worked. https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the ISO file was corrupt. Download a new one using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10?wa=wsignin1.0).

Full guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbJ_i32RraA

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem yesterday, and I would like to post my solution here just in case other people may have similar issues. Since I was reinstalling Windows 10, I can confirm the hardware is all in good condition. But I still get the error code 0x8007025D. The error code itself is not quite descriptive. Most of the posts online refer it to a hard drive or installation media corrupt. But if there is a hardware bug, at least the motherboard should tell me. I did not get any errors from the motherboard diagnosis.

Then, I thought it could be a memory bug. I cannot remember where I get this hint from. So I removed all the memory sticks and left only one slot occupied (I had four 8 GB memory sticks, so only 8 GB mem left). Then the problem was magically solved. To confirm it is the culprit, I plugged in the other memory sticks again and did another installation. The error code 0x8007025D pops up again. If I use only one memory stick, I can successfully install the second Windows 10. Although I don't know the root cause of the problem. But if you encounter this problem,
**try to remove some memory sticks before installation, and plug them back after you succeed.**

Probably, my solution is limited to specific hardware. Here is my hardware as a reference:

- Motherboard: ASUS Maximus X
- Memory: 8 GB Corsair 3200 MHz x4
- Hard drive: Samsung 970 Pro 1 TB x2
- CPU: Core i7 8700k